# Best Practice: Erlang Application Deploy on windows

Tags: deployment, erlang

When deploying a ready to use erlang application I **don't** want the user to

- Find the right erl release on the
  internet.
- Install the erl vm
- unzip and decide a location for the beam files (with the application)
- read a readme
- modify anything that even looks like a config file

I have a couple of ideas of what could be a way but I would like to get some input.

Comment: // , I have this same question about Elixir and Clojure. Functional programming languages need to attack their oft-deserved reputation of impracticality tooth and nail.

Answer (score 2):

SAE (stand-alone Erlang) used to be a pretty good solution for situations like you describe, but that no longer seems to be maintained.

Although I've never used it myself, [CEAN](http://cean.process-one.net/doc/) seems like it might come close to what you want: it offers a self-extracting installer (though not for Windows at present) and the option to deliver a customized minimal Erlang framework.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Erlware](http://erlware.org/).

> At our core we host public
>   repositories containing reliable
>   Erlang OTP-compliant applications. Our
>   repositories enable developers to use
>   software written by the Erlang
>   community and to publish and
>   distribute their own software.

It's more backend orient though, so not a complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

The [reltool](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/reltool/index.html) application first released with Erlang R13B02 is aimed at solving this issue. Note that it is currently a beta release (version 0.5).